# Consecutive asynchronous cudaMemcpy's with dependency

Tags: cuda

I have two consecutive `cudaMemcpyAsync` from device to host, put on the same stream. The first `cudaMemcpyAsync` copies a single `int`, which is the number of elements to be copied from device to host in the second `cudaMemcpyAsync`. A minimal code looks like that:

```cpp
cudaMemcpyAsync(h_size, d_size, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, copy_stream);
cudaMemcpyAsync(h_array, d_array, h_size[0]*sizeof(double), 
                cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, copy_stream);
```

It appears that the number of elements effectively copied in the second `cudaMemcpyAsync` corresponds to the value of `h_size[0]` *before* the first `cudaMemcpyAsync`. Somehow, as both memcopies are put on the same stream, I was (wrongly) expecting the second memcopy to read the correct (updated) value of `h_size[0]` at the right moment when it starts executing, namely after the first one has finished, since they should serialize on the same stream. What I understand from this example, is that the number of elements to be copied is somehow stored elsewhere by `cudaMemcpyAsync`, using the value encountered by the calling thread at the moment it hits that call, not at the moment it is executed.

The question is then: how can one make sure that the updated value of `h_size[0]` is used in the second `cudaMemcpyAsync` ?

First solution is to synchronize the stream between the two memcopies:

```cpp
cudaMemcpyAsync(h_size, d_size, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, copy_stream);
cudaStreamSynchronize(copy_stream);
cudaMemcpyAsync(h_array, d_array, h_size[0]*sizeof(double), 
                cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, copy_stream);
```

This works fine, however is far from optimal, as the CPU thread will block until the first communication is over. I want to avoid this situation, as the sequence of kernel launches and communication is put in a `for` loop, and the goal is to have the kernel from the next iteration launched as quickly as possible. The code snippet below is a complete working example of the structure of the code for illustration.

```cpp
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>

__global__
void kernel(double* d_array, int* d_size, int const k)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i==0) {
        printf("in kernel: d_size = %i\n", *d_size);
        if (k==0) {
            *d_size = 5;
        } else if (k==1) {
            *d_size = 3;
        } else {
            *d_size = 4;
        }
        printf("in kernel: d_size set to %i\n", *d_size);
        for (int i=0; i<3000; ++i) {
            __nanosleep(1000000U);
        }
    }
    d_array[i] += (1.0+(2.0+k)*i);
}

void communication(int * h_size, int const * d_size, 
                   double * h_array, double const * d_array,
                   cudaStream_t copy_stream,
                   cudaEvent_t compute_done,
                   cudaEvent_t copy_done)
{
    cudaStreamWaitEvent(copy_stream, compute_done, 0);
    // cudaMemcpyAsync in the next line will start as soon as the kernel execution is done
    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_size, d_size, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, copy_stream);

    // Solution 1: 
    //cudaStreamSynchronize(copy_stream);
    // Problem: the next kernel won't start before this point

    // the next cudaMemcpyAsync is on the same stream as the previous one --> they serialize
    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_array, d_array, 
                    h_size[0]*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, copy_stream);
    cudaEventRecord(copy_done, copy_stream);
}

void cpuWork(int const k, double const * h_array, int const * h_size)
{
    // here we check the values in h_array
    std::cout << "From kernel launch " << k << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<7; ++i) {
        std::cout << "h_array[" << i << "] = " << h_array[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "h_size[" << k%2 << "] = " << h_size[k%2] << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    int bufferSize = 1<<18;
    int blockSize = 256;
    int numBlocks = (bufferSize + blockSize - 1)/blockSize;

    int *h_size;
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&h_size, 2*sizeof(int));
    h_size[0] = 2;
    h_size[1] = 7; 
    
    int *d_size;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_size, 2*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_size, h_size, 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    double *h_array;
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&h_array, bufferSize*sizeof(double));
    for (int i=0; i<bufferSize; ++i) {h_array[i] = 0.14;}

    double *d_array;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_array, 2*bufferSize*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(d_array, h_array, bufferSize*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(&d_array[bufferSize], h_array, bufferSize*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaStream_t compute_stream[2], copy_stream;
    cudaEvent_t compute_done[2], copy_done;

    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&compute_stream[0], cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&compute_stream[1], cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&copy_stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&compute_done[0], cudaEventDisableTiming);
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&compute_done[1], cudaEventDisableTiming);
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&copy_done, cudaEventDisableTiming);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    
    // Launch the first kernel outside the FOR loop
    kernel<<<numBlocks, blockSize, 0, compute_stream[0]>>>(d_array, &d_size[0], 0);
    cudaEventRecord(compute_done[0], compute_stream[0]);
    
    int numCycles = 3;

    for (int k=1; k<numCycles; ++k) {
        
        // Communicate D-->H from the previous kernel launch, indexed k-1
        communication(&h_size[(k-1)%2], &d_size[(k-1)%2], 
                      h_array, &d_array[((k-1)%2)*bufferSize],
                      copy_stream, compute_done[(k-1)%2], copy_done);

        // Goal is to have this kernel start "asap" (even before the previous kernel has finished,
        // if the device has the capacity)
        kernel<<<numBlocks, blockSize, 0, compute_stream[k%2]>>>(
            &d_array[(k%2)*bufferSize], &d_size[k%2], k);
        cudaEventRecord(compute_done[k%2], compute_stream[k%2]);

        // Now do stuff on the CPU with h_array received from the (k-1)-th kernel launch
        cudaEventSynchronize(copy_done); // make sure communication is over
        cpuWork(k-1, h_array, h_size);
    }

    // Get results from the last cycle
    int k = numCycles-1;
    communication(&h_size[k%2], &d_size[k%2], 
                  h_array, &d_array[(k%2)*bufferSize],
                  copy_stream, compute_done[k%2], copy_done);

    // Now do work on the CPU with h_array received from the last kernel launch
    cudaEventSynchronize(copy_done); // make sure communication is over
    cpuWork(k, h_array, h_size);

    // clean
    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {cudaEventDestroy(compute_done[i]); 
                             cudaStreamDestroy(compute_stream[i]);}
    cudaEventDestroy(copy_done); cudaStreamDestroy(copy_stream);
    cudaFree(d_array); cudaFree(d_size);
    cudaFreeHost(h_array); cudaFreeHost(h_size);

    return 0;
}
```

with the following expected and effective output:

```
/* Expected result:
 * From kernel launch 0
 * h_array[0] = 1.14            ok
 * h_array[1] = 3.14            ok
 * h_array[2] = 5.14            NO  prints 0.14  means that h_size[0] was 2, not 5, at the 2nd cudaMemcpyAsync
 * h_array[3] = 7.14            NO  prints 0.14  :
 * h_array[4] = 9.14            NO  prints 0.14  :
 * h_array[5] = 0.14            ok
 * h_array[6] = 0.14            ok
 * h_size[0] = 5                ok
 * From kernel launch 1
 * h_array[0] = 1.14            ok
 * h_array[1] = 4.14            ok
 * h_array[2] = 7.14            ok  
 * h_array[3] = 7.14            NO  prints 10.14, means that h_size[1] was 7, not 3, at the 2nd cudaMemcpyAsync
 * h_array[4] = 9.14            NO  prints 13.14, 
 * h_array[5] = 0.14            NO  prints 16.14, 
 * h_array[6] = 0.14            NO  prints 19.14, 
 * h_size[1] = 3
 * From kernel launch 2
 * h_array[0] = 2.14            ok
 * h_array[1] = 8.14            ok
 * h_array[2] = 14.14           ok
 * h_array[3] = 20.14           ok
 * h_array[4] = 9.14            NO  prints 26.14, showing that h_size[0] was 5, not 4, at the 2nd cudaMemcpyAsync
 * h_array[5] = 0.14            NO  prints 16.14, 
 * h_array[6] = 0.14            NO  prints 19.14, 
 * h_size[0] = 4
*/
```

Comment: You could use a copy kernel which copies to pinned host memory.

Comment: "The question is then: how can one make sure that the updated value of `h_size[0]` is used in the second `cudaMemcpyAsync`?" You can't because `cudaMemcpyAsync` takes its parameters by value. It would need to take and address or reference to do what you want without synchronization. By using a copy kernel you can design the API to take a reference/pointer.

Comment: Thanks @AbatorAbetor and @paleonix. I tried to write down such a copy kernel but end up with the same problem (using either a `memcpy` inside a kernel, or otherwise passing directly pinned `h_size` in  my `kernel` instead of `d_size`). What would be the correct was to pass the reference to `h_size`, and not the value pointed when the calling thread hits the second `cudaMemcpyAsync` ?

Comment: The point is that your interface takes e.g. `size_t *`, and you pass it `d_size` which will only be dereferenced **inside** the kernel. Naturally that means that you can't use it to calculate the number of blocks needed, but just launching as many blocks as can run simultaneously on your particular GPU and the using e.g. a grid-stride loop inside the kernel should be fine performance-wise.

Comment: sorry, I am confused now. The kernel only needs to copy a single `int`, so I was thinking of using only one thread to do the copy, while the remaining ones in the kernel just "do nothing". But the issue is about the referencing of the destination.

Comment: You could asynchronously call a host function (`cudaLaunchHostFunc`), which in turn adds the second `cudaMemcpyAsync`. But it cannot do so directly, as those callbacks are not allowed to call any Cuda function.

Comment: suppose you knew the maximum size of the possible transfer for the final `cudaMemcpyAsync` call (i.e. the maximum value that `h_size[0]` could be).  I think this could be knowable because the (size of the) allocations for `h_array` and `d_array` have that information implicitly.  You could elect to always copy the maximum possible size (perhaps into a temporary or separate buffer), then when it becomes time to consume that data on the host (i.e. the data in `h_array`), then you would inspect the actual value of the `h_size` and copy only that much data from your temporary buffer to `h_array`.

Answer (score 1):

A copy-kernel can be used with pinned memory instead of `cudaMemcpyAsync`. The kernel reads the number of elements to copy from a pointer. It also uses a grid-strided loop to work with any number of threads.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <iostream>

__global__
void computeNumToCopyKernel(int* output){
    *output = 5;
}

__global__
void copyKernel(const int* input, int* output, const int* numToCopyPtr){
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    const int numToCopy = *numToCopyPtr;

    for(int i = tid; i < numToCopy; i += stride){
        output[i] = input[i];
    }
}

int main(){
    const int N = 10;
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_numbers(N);
    thrust::sequence(d_numbers.begin(), d_numbers.end(), 0);

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_numToCopy(1);

    int* h_copiedNumbers;
    cudaMallocHost(&h_copiedNumbers, sizeof(int) * N);

    computeNumToCopyKernel<<<1,1>>>(d_numToCopy.data().get());
    copyKernel<<<32, 128>>>(d_numbers.data().get(), h_copiedNumbers, d_numToCopy.data().get());
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cout << h_copiedNumbers[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

The following code is your example code with a copy kernel

```
#include <iostream>

__global__
void kernel(double* d_array, int* d_size, int const k)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i==0) {
        printf("in kernel: d_size = %i\n", *d_size);
        if (k==0) {
            *d_size = 5;
        } else if (k==1) {
            *d_size = 3;
        } else {
            *d_size = 4;
        }
        printf("in kernel: d_size set to %i\n", *d_size);
        for (int i=0; i<3000; ++i) {
            __nanosleep(1000000U);
        }
    }
    d_array[i] += (1.0+(2.0+k)*i);
}

template<class T>
__global__
void copyKernel(const T* input, T* output, const int* numToCopyPtr){
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    const int numToCopy = *numToCopyPtr;

    for(int i = tid; i < numToCopy; i += stride){
        output[i] = input[i];
    }
}

void communication(int * h_size, int const * d_size, 
                   double * h_array, double const * d_array,
                   cudaStream_t copy_stream,
                   cudaEvent_t compute_done,
                   cudaEvent_t copy_done)
{
    cudaStreamWaitEvent(copy_stream, compute_done, 0);
    // cudaMemcpyAsync in the next line will start as soon as the kernel execution is done
    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_size, d_size, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, copy_stream);

    // Solution 1: 
    //cudaStreamSynchronize(copy_stream);
    // Problem: the next kernel won't start before this point

    // the next cudaMemcpyAsync is on the same stream as the previous one --> they serialize
    // cudaMemcpyAsync(h_array, d_array, 
    //                 h_size[0]*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, copy_stream);

    copyKernel<<<32, 128, 0, copy_stream>>>(d_array, h_array, d_size);

    cudaEventRecord(copy_done, copy_stream);
}

void cpuWork(int const k, double const * h_array, int const * h_size)
{
    // here we check the values in h_array
    std::cout << "From kernel launch " << k << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<7; ++i) {
        std::cout << "h_array[" << i << "] = " << h_array[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "h_size[" << k%2 << "] = " << h_size[k%2] << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    int bufferSize = 1<<18;
    int blockSize = 256;
    int numBlocks = (bufferSize + blockSize - 1)/blockSize;

    int *h_size;
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&h_size, 2*sizeof(int));
    h_size[0] = 2;
    h_size[1] = 7; 
    
    int *d_size;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_size, 2*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_size, h_size, 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    double *h_array;
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&h_array, bufferSize*sizeof(double));
    for (int i=0; i<bufferSize; ++i) {h_array[i] = 0.14;}

    double *d_array;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_array, 2*bufferSize*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(d_array, h_array, bufferSize*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(&d_array[bufferSize], h_array, bufferSize*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaStream_t compute_stream[2], copy_stream;
    cudaEvent_t compute_done[2], copy_done;

    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&compute_stream[0], cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&compute_stream[1], cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&copy_stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&compute_done[0], cudaEventDisableTiming);
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&compute_done[1], cudaEventDisableTiming);
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&copy_done, cudaEventDisableTiming);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    
    // Launch the first kernel outside the FOR loop
    kernel<<<numBlocks, blockSize, 0, compute_stream[0]>>>(d_array, &d_size[0], 0);
    cudaEventRecord(compute_done[0], compute_stream[0]);
    
    int numCycles = 3;

    for (int k=1; k<numCycles; ++k) {
        
        // Communicate D-->H from the previous kernel launch, indexed k-1
        communication(&h_size[(k-1)%2], &d_size[(k-1)%2], 
                      h_array, &d_array[((k-1)%2)*bufferSize],
                      copy_stream, compute_done[(k-1)%2], copy_done);

        // Goal is to have this kernel start "asap" (even before the previous kernel has finished,
        // if the device has the capacity)
        kernel<<<numBlocks, blockSize, 0, compute_stream[k%2]>>>(
            &d_array[(k%2)*bufferSize], &d_size[k%2], k);
        cudaEventRecord(compute_done[k%2], compute_stream[k%2]);

        // Now do stuff on the CPU with h_array received from the (k-1)-th kernel launch
        cudaEventSynchronize(copy_done); // make sure communication is over
        cpuWork(k-1, h_array, h_size);
    }

    // Get results from the last cycle
    int k = numCycles-1;
    communication(&h_size[k%2], &d_size[k%2], 
                  h_array, &d_array[(k%2)*bufferSize],
                  copy_stream, compute_done[k%2], copy_done);

    // Now do work on the CPU with h_array received from the last kernel launch
    cudaEventSynchronize(copy_done); // make sure communication is over
    cpuWork(k, h_array, h_size);

    // clean
    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {cudaEventDestroy(compute_done[i]); 
                             cudaStreamDestroy(compute_stream[i]);}
    cudaEventDestroy(copy_done); cudaStreamDestroy(copy_stream);
    cudaFree(d_array); cudaFree(d_size);
    cudaFreeHost(h_array); cudaFreeHost(h_size);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above prints

```
in kernel: d_size = 2
in kernel: d_size set to 5
From kernel launch 0
h_array[0] = 1.14
h_array[1] = 3.14
h_array[2] = 5.14
h_array[3] = 7.14
h_array[4] = 9.14
h_array[5] = 0.14
h_array[6] = 0.14
h_size[0] = 5
in kernel: d_size = 7
in kernel: d_size set to 3
in kernel: d_size = 5
in kernel: d_size set to 4
From kernel launch 1
h_array[0] = 1.14
h_array[1] = 4.14
h_array[2] = 7.14
h_array[3] = 7.14
h_array[4] = 9.14
h_array[5] = 0.14
h_array[6] = 0.14
h_size[1] = 3
From kernel launch 2
h_array[0] = 2.14
h_array[1] = 8.14
h_array[2] = 14.14
h_array[3] = 20.14
h_array[4] = 9.14
h_array[5] = 0.14
h_array[6] = 0.14
h_size[0] = 4
```